# Router ARP Table

Tags: arp

I have attached the topology, PC0 and PC1 are in same network (192.168.1.0/24)

PC0 send packet PC1 directly after arp resolution. So why router arp table shows PC0 and PC1 mac address. (Although the packet does not pass the router)[image]

Comment: but if hosts are in same network why they send the packet to default gateway ?

Comment: communication between hosts will not reach the gateway. But can you be sure that *no traffic at all* was sent to the router?  If the router is DHCP server and/or default gateway for example, you can be sure there was traffic. Any broadcast traffic coming from the PC's will reach the router as well.

Comment: You really need to include the network device configurations.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

If the hosts exchanged traffic with the router, which is very likely if you configured the router to be the default gateway for these PC's, the router will have learned their MAC addresses and will have stored their ARP entries.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the router to learnt those MAC addresses of PC0 and PC1 ( in the ARP table) is because of **Gratuitous arp**. Gratuitous arp will be used when network node boots up or ip address is changed so that other nodes will know the presence.

[Gratuitous ARP could mean both gratuitous ARP request or gratuitous ARP reply. Gratuitous in this case means a request/reply that is not normally needed according to the ARP specification (RFC 826) but could be used in some cases. A gratuitous ARP request is anAddressResolutionProtocol request packet where the source and destination IP are both set to the IP of the machine issuing the packet and the destination MAC is the broadcast address ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff. Ordinarily, no reply packet will occur. A gratuitous ARP reply is a reply to which no request has been made.](https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/lan-switching-and-routing/what-is-gratuitous-arp/td-p/2515809)